# 503 error on apache virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, 503-error

I created a virtual host with the following code on an ubuntu apache server

```
cd /var/www/
sudo mkdir fd-pro
sudo mkdir /var/www/fd-pro/ch-api
sudo mkdir /var/www/fd-pro/ch-api/public_html
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/fd-pro/ch-api/public_html
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/*
nano /var/www/fd-pro/ch-api/public_html/index.html
```

And created index.html

Then

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.mydomain.com.au.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/fd-pro/ch-api/public_html
    ServerName domain.mydomain.com.au
    ServerAlias domain.mydomain.com.au

    <Directory /var/www/fd-pro/ch-api/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain-error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

sudo a2ensite domain.mydomain.com.au.conf

sudo service apache2 restart
```

No errors were displayed, but sever responds with 503 error. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is mod headers is not enabled in apache.

Answer (score 1):

> No errors were displayed, but sever responds with 503 error. Can anyone help me?

Yes, go and look in you apache error log, which should be located in /var/log/apache2/.

The error log should contain more detailed information about what the problem is. You should use that to diagnose what the problem is. google (other search engines are available) will be helpful too once you have found the problem in your logs.

Answer (score 1):

```
Require all granted
```

is valid for [apache 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html).

The [equivalent for apache 2.2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) is:

```
Allow from all
```

Answer (score 0):

There is of course some apache log files. Search in your apache configuration files for 'Log' keyword, you'll certainly find plenty of them. Depending on your OS and installation places may vary (in a Typical Linux server it would be **/var/log/apache2/[access|error].log**).

Having a 503 error in Apache usually means **the proxied page/service is not available**.

Comment: What configuration makes you assume that there is Tomcat or even a proxy involved?

Comment: > `ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain-error.log` doesn't need to search it's explicitly defined already and will generally be in /var/log/apache2

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I'm using a proxy server on my system and it's enough to turn off the proxy server (disable) or just ignore the localhost(and the virtual hosts that I'm running on Apache) when using the proxy.